# Creating an (k)Integer and (v)Set TreeMap from a list in Java

Tags: java, list, key-value, treemap

My aim is to fill a TreeMap with keys as Integer values, and values as a set of elements from a list. 
For example say I have a list like:

```
1 big 345,
1 small 223,
2 big 312,
1 small 116
```

I'd like the keys of the TreeMap to be the first number, and the values to be sets of the elements in the list. So the map would look like:

```
1(K)
1 big 345(V)
1 small 223(V)
1 small 116(V)

2(K)
2 big 312(V)
```

I'm not sure how to implement this, the only code I have written is just to define a tree map and to copy the list into a set. I don't know how I would associate the key to value. Any help is appreciated and will add more info if I am unclear.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your List contains Foo instances and the int value is represented by an `id` field, you could get as result a `TreeMap<Integer, Set<Foo>>` object with :

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
TreeMap<Integer, Set<Foo>>` map = new TreeMap<>();
for (Foo foo : foos){
   map.computeIfAbsent(foo.getId() k-> new HashSet<>())
      .add(foo);
}
```